# PostgreSQL array(row_to_json()): How to stop array() functions from adding " quotes to strings and escape \ existing " quotes

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

Trying to return a properly formatted JSON object as a single field result.

row_to_json() works very nicely but returns multiple rows.

```
SELECT row_to_json(ages) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT('000' || TRIM(age),3) AS v FROM uspopulation GROUP BY v ORDER BY v) AS ages
```

The resulting rows are nicely formatted JSON but one per row:

```
{"v":"000"}
```

Then I want to process that result set into an array in a single row/col result:

```
SELECT array(
SELECT row_to_json(ages) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT('000' || TRIM(age),3) AS v FROM uspopulation GROUP BY v ORDER BY v) AS ages
);
```

This achieves the desired result.  However, it adds double quotes around each JSON object and escapes the existing quotes in the properly formatted JSON object.

```
{"{\"v\":\"000\"}","{\"v\":\"001\"}","{\"v\":\"002\"}"}
```

So how do I turn off this behavior so I get a result like this:

```
{{"v":"000"},{"v":"001"},{"v":"002"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_agg()` to aggregate the results:

```
SELECT json_agg(ages) FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT('000' || TRIM(age),3) AS v
   FROM uspopulation GROUP BY v ORDER BY v) AS ages;
```

This will give the correct output. Do note, that the output is not as you described, since it's an array:

```
[{"v":"000"},{"v":"001"},{"v":"002"}]
```

I assume this is what you want, since it is the correct notation for a JSON array.